# Unable to manipulate files and directories while building docker image

Tags: docker, wildfly

In Dockerfile i have this :

```
FROM jboss/base-jdk:8

ENV WILDFLY_VERSION 10.1.0.Final
ENV JBOSS_HOME /opt/jboss/wildfly
ENV config $JBOSS_HOME/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/domain/configuration
ENV master_address 192.168.56.10
ENV tmp /tmp/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/domain/configuration

COPY wildfly-10.1.0.Final.tar.gz /tmp/wildfly-10.1.0.Final.tar.gz
RUN cd /tmp/
RUN tar xf /tmp/wildfly-10.1.0.Final.tar.gz -C /tmp/

RUN sed -i -e 's/noed_name/$HOSTNAME/g' $tmp/host.xml
RUN sed -i -e 's/host_master/$master_address/g' $tmp/host.xml
RUN sed -i -e 's/secret_value/$secret/g' $tmp/host.xml

RUN mv /tmp/wildfly-10.1.0.Final $JBOSS_HOME/
RUN rm /tmp/wildfly-10.1.0.Final.tar.gz

RUN secret=$(echo $HOSTNAME | base64 )

ENV LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND true

EXPOSE 8330
EXPOSE 9999

CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/bin/domain.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0"]
```

The error : unable to remove evry file and directory under `/tmp/wildfly-10.1.0.Final`

```
 mv: cannot remove '/tmp/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/welcome-content/wildfly.css': No such file or directory
...
The command '/bin/sh -c mv /tmp/wildfly-10.1.0.Final $JBOSS_HOME/' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

PS : Before i was unable to run `tar`, the command return `No such a file or directory` until i switch to tmp folder, also `sed` command.

Comment: Your line `secret=...` is "lost" as long as the next line is processed, use `ENV...` if you need it

Comment: Do you create /opt/jboss/wildfly in boss/basejdk:8? If not, you need to create this directory

Comment: @user2915097 i added `RUN mkdir /opt/jboss/wildfly -p` same result, from what i see the user who execute `mv` command doesn't have permission but don't know why and how to resolve this.

Comment: The Dockerfile https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/base-jdk/~/dockerfile/ leads to https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/base/~/dockerfile/ so you are the user jboss, 1000:1000

Comment: Indeed, i switch to root by adding `USER root` same problem remain !

Comment: `RUN cd /tmp/` on its own line does nothing. Replace that with `WORKDIR /tmp` if you want to switch into the `/tmp` directory for later commands.

Comment: you should group your RUN, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/

Answer (score 1):

In my machine I disn't have the problem you showed. I have this other:

```
Step 14/18 : RUN rm /tmp/wildfly-10.1.0.Final.tar.gz
 ---> Running in c4a839a8bf8b
rm: cannot remove '/tmp/wildfly-10.1.0.Final.tar.gz': Operation not permitted
```

I was able to fix it surrounding the `rm` with the proper users:

```
...
USER root
RUN rm /tmp/wildfly-10.1.0.Final.tar.gz
USER jboss
...
```

I've downloaded wildfly from here:

```
http://download.jboss.org/wildfly/10.1.0.Final/wildfly-10.1.0.Final.tar.gz
```

Then your Dockerfile becomes this:

```
FROM jboss/base-jdk:8

ENV WILDFLY_VERSION 10.1.0.Final
ENV JBOSS_HOME /opt/jboss/wildfly
ENV config $JBOSS_HOME/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/domain/configuration
ENV master_address 192.168.56.10
ENV tmp /tmp/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/domain/configuration

COPY wildfly-10.1.0.Final.tar.gz /tmp/wildfly-10.1.0.Final.tar.gz
RUN cd /tmp/
RUN tar xf /tmp/wildfly-10.1.0.Final.tar.gz -C /tmp/

RUN sed -i -e 's/noed_name/$HOSTNAME/g' $tmp/host.xml
RUN sed -i -e 's/host_master/$master_address/g' $tmp/host.xml
RUN sed -i -e 's/secret_value/$secret/g' $tmp/host.xml

RUN mv /tmp/wildfly-10.1.0.Final $JBOSS_HOME/

USER root
RUN rm /tmp/wildfly-10.1.0.Final.tar.gz
USER jboss

RUN secret=$(echo $HOSTNAME | base64 )

ENV LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND true

EXPOSE 8330
EXPOSE 9999

CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/bin/domain.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0"]
```

It's working:

```
$ docker build .
..
..
..
Step 21/21 : CMD /opt/jboss/wildfly/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/bin/domain.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement 0.0.0.0
 ---> Running in 06a9043977bc
 ---> ab4b6a623f3f
Removing intermediate container 06a9043977bc
Successfully built ab4b6a623f3f
```

You can try again discarding the previous chache: `docker build . --no-cache`

Comment: Still not able to remove folder from `/tmp`!!  When i change `USER` and `WORKDIR` i was able to work under `/opt/jboss` but not `/tmp`

Comment: I have `No such a file or directory` not `Operation not permitted`

Comment: Docker versión?

Comment: Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be